# In "Sort the extensions by **the** date of **the** last extension update.", are the two last "the" optional?

Tags: determiners

In "Sort the extensions by **the** date of **the** last extension update.", are the two last "the" optional?

In other words, should one say

> Sort the extensions by date of last extension update.

or

> Sort the extensions by **the** date of **the** last extension update.

?

Comment: I would say the first "the" can be optional, but I don't have a reason. In fact, you could say "Sort the extensions by date of the last extension update" but you could NOT say "Sort the extensions by the date of last extension update"

Comment: @Danneyland Thanks, interesting!

Comment: I think we use "by date" rather like a phrase (a preposition? Something like that), so it doesn't need the determiner "the".